Using Rstudio diagnostics with non-standard evaluation eg from tidyverse
I am a long time user of R and Rstudio but I have never tried to use all the diagnostics reporting tools. However, after a while using spyder for python and finding the tools there useful and being given a painful task of going through some old scripts which are a huge mess to tidy them up I was hoping to make use of the tools. My problem is pretty simple, as soon as I turn "Warn if variable has no definition in scope" on all tidyverse code using non-standard evaluation is highlighted as having no definition in scope (see image below). The scripts I have to go through have a lot of code of this nature making this totally useless.
I assumed there would be a lot of discussion about this on the internet as it seems it must be a very common occurrence, however all I can find is these two blog posts:
Possible solutions for "no symbol named 'x' in scope"
One Solution to “no symbol named ‘x’ in scope” When Referencing Column Names in ggplot()
Neither of these provide valid solutions for actually working with tidyverse, and for example would fail on grouped data.
Have other people got workarounds that they use? Does everyone who writes in tidyverse just turn off this diagnostic reporting and not worry about it? That is a valid possibility and what I have always done but for cleaning up these old scripts I thought it would be helpful as a starting point.
I also noticed for the first time the "extract function" keyboard shortcut and thought this would be useful, but once again it is converting every column into an argument which are not actually used. I assume this is related.

********* Edit **********
In response to comments I realise this is probably a version issue. I was using R 4.3.1 with RStudio 2023.06.1, I have tried it on a different computer with R 4.4.0 and RStudio 2024.04.2 and it is not reproducing

It's not reproducible at my end (R 4.4.1, RStudio  2024.04.2, Windows, project packages installed through renv,  minimal number of global packages).

OP should declare what what version of R and Rstudio is showing the behaviour.

Interesting, I didn't think about this but probably should have. I just tried on a different computer with different versions and it is working fine. I will update question with versions, but leave it as a question so others like me think of checking the version
